# How to create a caching/swapping/ in memory cache

Tags: c#, windows, caching

I would like to implement something like [FancyCache](http://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/fancy-cache/) or [SuperCache](http://www.superspeed.com/desktop/supercache.php).

The software creates a swap file. The disk IO is a bottleneck. I need to have some files in RAM because I need them to be fast.

I don't need the full file, only some blocks. I dont put the whole file in a RAM disk because it is about 40gb. But there are some blocks of this file that need to be in memory.

Softwares that I mentiond do it with the most frequent files. But I only need to do it with one file.

This is for a virtualzation environment.

Do yo have any guides of how I can create this kind of cache simulating a Swap file of Windows?

Comment: Why do you need to manage swap yourself?  Just create the objects representing the data you need, and let the OS handle swap if necessary.

Comment: In this scenario it doesn't work. I am using Hyper-V and need to have a VHD in memory. The swaping doesn't work for hyper-v, thats why Microsoft create  RAM Cache in the CSV (Storage for virtual machines) in Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're describing to *persisted memory-mapped files*. The file will be mapped into your virtual memory, and it's up to the operating system to read and cache items from the physical drive.

Read more on MSDN: [Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx)

Comment: To expand on this, you can select specific parts of the file to map into "views" in memory, so you can use this approach even if the file is larger than your virtual address space.

Comment: @Simon But the file will have memory access only for the program or the whole OS? What I need for a virtualization scenario is for the whole OS

Comment: It's the process who has mapped the file to the virtual memory space. Several processes can do this with the same file, assuming security and sharing parameters allow it. Try it out, profile and adjust if there are any issues with performance.

Answer (score -2):

What I would do is start with a class like this:

```
public class SwapData
{
    public const int BlockSize = 1024;

    private int HotCount {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private long Offset {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private byte[] Data {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private string FileName {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class SwapFile
{
    private List<SwapData> _swapData;

    public string SwapFileName
    { get; set; }

    public byte[] ReadData(string fileName, long offset, int numBytes)
    {
        if (!Cached(fileName, offset))
        {
            return StoreCache(fileName, offset);
        } else return Cache(fileName, offset, numBytes);
    }

    private bool Cached(string fileName, long offset)
    {
        return _swapData.Any(z => z.FileName.ToLower().Equals(fileName.ToLower()) && z.Offset >= offset);
    }

    private byte[] StoreCache(string fileName, long offset)
    {
        using (var bw = new BinaryReader(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))) 
        {
            bw.BaseStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var sd = new SwapData();
            sd.HotCount = 0;
            sd.Office = offset;
            sd.FileName = fileName;
            sd.Data = bw.ReadBytes(sd.BlockSize);
            _swapData.Add(sd);
            return sd.Data;
        }
    }

    private byte[] Cache(string fileName, long offset, int numBytes)
    {
        byte[] data = _swapData.FirstOrDefault(z => z.FileName.ToLower().Equals(fileName.ToLower()) && z.Offset >= offset).Data;

        byte[] target = new byte[numBytes];
        Array.Copy(data,target,numBytes);
        return target;
    }
```

I haven't tested this yet, but it would go something like that ^^^

Comment: It would require quite a lot of work to make your code work. Right now, for example, if I try to read from offset `1` and then from offset `0`, the returned data will be from offset `1`. And reading more than `BlockSize` doesn't work. And I'm sure there are other problems in this code. (And that's after fixing some compilation errors.)

Comment: @svick - As I said, I haven't tested it. Its not meant for him to just copy and paste. Its meant as more of an idea as to how it would be done, if he was interested. I left out all offset checks and null checks intentianally so I could just show the point

Comment: Like I said, I think this is too far from working code. I think it's more like a start of an idea, which makes it not a very useful answer.

Comment: @icemanind - An idea as to how it would be done *can be* a valid answer, but it should be short and to the point, preferably with links to more documentation and / or comments indicating the "Do it yourself" portions.  This is too long and unexplained for that, but since it doesn't work as-is, it's not useful either.